# PUT Request with Attribute Routing - Error 415

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, caldav

I've got a PUT request from clients that looks like this:

```
PUT /calendars/johndoe/home/132456762153245.ics HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8
```

I have a controller class setup with Attribute routing and a Method like so:

```
[HttpPut]
[Consumes("text/calendar")
[Route("calendars/{userName:alpha}/{calendarName:alpha}/{icsFile}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Put([FromRoute] string userName, [FromRoute] string calendarName, [FromBody] string icsFile)

        {...
```

I've tried different Route Attributes and a catch-all parameter but it does not work with the whole url path.

I get an error 415 response - media type unsupported

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your route attribute

```
[Route("calendars/{userName}/{calendarName}/{icsFile}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Put( string userName, string calendarName,  string icsFile)
{
....
}
```

and IMHO it is better to remove [HttpPut] and [Consumes("text/calendar")]

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: Thanks! Based on your example, Removing the [FromBody] parameter was a clue! That started to allow requests to get picked up. Turns out, there is no parser to text content type and that's why the content type was being rejected. I now just read the stream from body to get the text.